# Is this a cactus?

Tags: identification, seedlings, cactus

I recently bought cacti seedlings. After one month they don't look like cacti. Any ideas on what this might be?

*<sub>Click photo for full size</sub>*
[image: picture]

Comment: Probably not a cactus. But you have to wait for some more leaves for identification. Now I'd guess it is basil :)

Comment: @Ariser Agreed, but not on basil - the cotyledon here are longish, basil is shorter, more rounded, slightly triangular(-ish).

Comment: the little hairs at the bottom were there from the beginning. Could these be a clue? :)

Answer (score 2):

Whatever it is it is getting TOO MUCH WATER and there is no drainage.  Needs an awful lot more light.  Succulent type/cactus type plants store their own water, they have very shallow roots, need a clay pot that breathes, potting soil for cactus type plants, make the pot wider than tall.  Whatever plant this is, there are an awful lot of them.  I'd break them up and put them in tiny pots with cactus potting soil, spray with water to moisten only the top 1/2 " of soil, allow to dry a bit before spraying again.  Don't worry about fertilizer now, these plants need to get established first.  Are these indoor plants?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I bought cactus soil, made it a bit wet and put it in the microwave for a few minutes. In a plastic cup with holes in the bottem, I put the seeds on top of the soil and sprinkled it some more. I put everything in a closed zip bag and placed it next to the window. This might not be the right way to do this then? :-) I will break them up ASAP!